# There is a large empty white space at the end of my html, using wordpress theme I made

Tags: php, html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have checked the css and there is a reset in there. I have checked the php for an empty line.. can't figure out where this white space is coming from. I've tried all suggestions from people with the same issue on this site but it's not working. this is the live site:
http://www.forewardsapp.com/blog/

Comment: I found in the console if you delete in the css: `margin: 0;` it gets rid of the white space. Not exactly sure why yet though. EDIT: if i scroll down the white space comes back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `<iframe>` inside a `div` with id `"_atssh"` just before `</body>`, it is causing the white space at the bottom. Fix it.

To be more precise:

Change the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` of the `iframe` in the `blog-styles.css` on line  `70`

Answer (score 1):

You have an HTML element at the bottom with `id="_atssh"` this has the CSS property `position:absolute;` that's what's causing the white space.

You could add another CSS rule to over write it...

```
#_atssh {
    position:relative !important; 
}
```

The `!important` will make sure your CSS rule is not overwritten by any other rules `#_atssh`.

**Be aware** that people will say `!important` is **bad**!!! [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

When I use Firebug when going to your "White Space" it seems like it is your body sticking out from under your footer. 
Perhaps there is a margin-bottom/padding/bottom value set at your footer.